# iOS - Concurrency performing 5 operations uploading images to server using NSOperationQueue followed by single Task in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsoperationqueue, reachability

**I have to perform below operations using nsoperationqueue concurrently.**

***I need to perform multiple operations in background at a time like 5(Uploading
    files to Server) , i have to manage all queues depends up on follow scenorio***

- 1) network is 2G only perform 1 Operation,remaining 4 operations
  should be stop
- 2) network is either 3G/Wifi perform all operations parallally.

How can i achieve this Using Objective-c???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try this way(Add observer for internet monitoring and do the handling of NSOperationQueue operations),

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182128/upload-multiple-images-using-afnetworking

Comment: You can use Reachability class provided by apple @ https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

or check out tonymillion's custom reachability class mentioned in the link along with Native Reachability class of apple implementation also.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926026/objective-c-reachability-class

Comment: I would discourage from using NSOperationQueue in this use case. In order to gain a minuscule benefit from using it - as opposed to other approaches, you need to create a concurrent NSOperation subclass, which is surprisingly error prone and elaborate. IMHO, you are better off just calling asynchronous functions (with a completion handler) and leverage a `DispatchGroup` (and `enter`, `leave` and `notify` respectively) to serialise your network requests. The larger the payload, the less benefit you gain from parallelising the requests, anyway.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, if you have any solution please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet status and handle a operation as require

**Serial Dispatch Queues**

In serial queue each task waits for the previous task to finish before being executed.

When network is slow you can use it.

```
let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.imagesQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL) 

dispatch_async(serialQueue) { () -> Void in
    let img1 = Downloader .downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[0])
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.imageView1.image = img1
   })      
}

dispatch_async(serialQueue) { () -> Void in
   let img2 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[1])
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
       self.imageView2.image = img2
   })
}
```

**Concurrent Queue**

Each downloader is considered as a task and all tasks are being performed in same time.

When network fast use it.

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in

        let img1 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[0])
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            self.imageView1.image = img1
        })

}

dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in

        let img2 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[1])

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            self.imageView2.image = img2
        })

}
```

**NSOpration**

When you need to start an operation that depends on the execution of the other, you will want to use NSOperation.

You can also set a priority of operation.

`addDependency` for different `operation`

```
queue = OperationQueue()

let operation1 = BlockOperation(block: {
     let img1 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(url: imageURLs[0])
     OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
          self.imgView1.image = img1
     })
})

// completionBlock for operation        
operation1.completionBlock = {
    print("Operation 1 completed")
}

// Add Operation into queue
queue.addOperation(operation1)

let operation2 = BlockOperation(block: {
     let img2 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(url: imageURLs[1])
     OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
          self.imgView2.image = img2
     })
})

// Operation 2 are depend on operation 1. when operation 1 completed after operation 2 is execute. 
operation2.addDependency(operation1)

queue.addOperation(operation2)
```

You can also set a priority

```
public enum NSOperationQueuePriority : Int {
    case VeryLow
    case Low
    case Normal
    case High
    case VeryHigh
}
```

You can also set a concurrent operation

```
queue = OperationQueue()

queue.addOperation { () -> Void in

    let img1 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(url: imageURLs[0])

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
        self.imgView1.image = img1
    })
 }
```

you can also cancel and finish operation.

Comment: Okay i will convert it @Priya